# Facebook share button in hidden div

Tags: html, facebook

I need to show a fb-share-button in `div`. This `div` initially are hidden by `display:none` css property. In **IE** when the fb-share-button are in a hidden `div`, the button doesn't show, and when the `div` is showed the button continues hidden.

I try to wait the button are loaded and hide the `div` after, but I have no success.

This is my code:
Master.Page:

```
<div id="fb-root">
</div>

<script>

    (function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/es_ES/sdk.js#xfbml=1&appId=536816803117001&version=v2.1";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    } (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

The code for show content and buttons:

```
<div id="SP_PublicacionesCapsula1" class="SP_PublicacionesSeccionOff">
                <ul class="SinTipo SinMarginSinPadding">
                    <%  for (Int16 i = 0; i < drInformes.Count; i++)
                        {%>
                    <li class="SP_PublicacionesSeccionItem">
                        <dl class="SP_PublicacionesSeccionItemTexto">
                            <dt><a class="SP_PublicacionesTitulo" href="../SalaPrensa/PublicacionesEstudioCasos.aspx?Est_Id=<%=drInformes[i]["Est_Id"].GetInt()%>&Est_Tipo=1" title="enlace a <%=drInformes[i]["Est_Titulo"].GetPublishString(40)%>">
                                <%=drInformes[i]["Est_Titulo"].GetPublishString()%></a></dt>
                            <dd class="SinMarginSinPadding">
                                <%=drInformes[i]["Est_Resumen"].GetPublishHtml()%></dd>
                        </dl>
                        <a href="../SalaPrensa/PublicacionesEstudioCasos.aspx?Est_Id=<%=drInformes[i]["Est_Id"].GetInt()%>&Est_Tipo=1" title="acceder a la información completa de <%=drInformes[i]["Est_Titulo"].GetPublishString(40)%>">
                            <img alt="icono de acceso a la información completa de <%=drInformes[i]["Est_Titulo"].GetPublishString(40)%>" src="../_img/<%=Tools.RecursosCarpeta(this)%>Flecha.png" class="SP_PublicacionesEstudiosFlecha" /></a>
                        <div style="clear: both">
                            &nbsp;</div>
                        <!--twitter-->
                        <div style="float: left; width: 90px;">
                            <a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-lang="en" data-url="<%= GetUrl(drInformes[i]["Est_Id"].GetInt(), 1)%>" data-counturl="<%= GetUrl(drInformes[i]["Est_Id"].GetInt(), 1)%>" data-text="<%=drInformes[i]["Est_Titulo"].GetPublishString()%>">Tweet</a>
                        </div>
                        <!--facebook-->
                        <div style="height: 20px!important; float: left; margin-top: 1px; display: block!important;">
                            <div class="fb-share-button" data-href="<%= GetUrl(drInformes[i]["Est_Id"].GetInt(), 1)%>" data-type="button_count">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <%  }%>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

The styles for divs showing o hidding:

```
.SP_PublicacionesSeccionOff
{   
    display:none;
    float:left; 
    width:529px;
}
.SP_PublicacionesSeccionOn
{
    display:block;
    float:left; 
    width:529px;
}
```

Finally the code JS for show or hide:

```
function AbrirDesplegable(Contenedor, SeccionEnlace, Identificador, Flecha) {

var contenedor = new Object();
var desplegable = new Object();
var flecha = new Object();
var seccion = new Object();

contenedor = document.getElementById(Contenedor);
desplegable = document.getElementById(Identificador);
flecha = document.getElementById(Flecha);
seccion = document.getElementById(SeccionEnlace);

if (desplegable.className == 'SP_PublicacionesSeccionOn') {
    seccion.className = 'SP_PublicacionesSeccionTextoLinkOff';
    flecha.src = '../_img/Flecha[Off].gif';
    desplegable.className = 'SP_PublicacionesSeccionOff';
}
else {
    seccion.className = 'SP_PublicacionesSeccionTextoLinkOn';
    flecha.src = '../_img/Flecha[On].gif';
    desplegable.className = 'SP_PublicacionesSeccionOn';
}

}
```

Comment: Can you add what you've got?

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to parse the button after making it visible:

```
FB.XFBML.parse();
```

More information: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse

Also, make sure the pages where you are using Social Plugins are public and not only available behind password protected areas.

Comment: is your page live? - for testing and because it MUST be live/public for the facebook social plugins to work correctly.

Comment: No, my page are in develop site, but others buttons in not hide divs work correctly, and if I run the page on Chrome the buttons are showed.

Comment: may be the problem then, facebook needs to be able to access the page where the social plugin is implemented. not sure why it works for some elements though, but if some plugin does not show it´s most likely because it´s not a public page or you need to use XFBML.parse. try it on a live page.